# Simple way to inject working directory full path in Composer script

Tags: cmd, composer-php

I use Composer to execute a third-party command-line script that needs a path as argument:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "i18n-extract": [
            "foo.bat init --path . --quiet",
            "foo.bat extras --path . --quiet"
        ]
    }
}
```

Due to an series of bugs in third-party components, using a relative path like `.` does not work correctly and I'm forced to provide a full absolute path with duplicate trailing backslashes:

```
C:\Projects\Project name\src\\
```

… which, encoded for JSON, results in:

```
"foo.bat init --path \"C:\\Projects\\Project name\\src\\\\\" --quiet"
```

But I can't hard-code paths because the script is meant to be redistributed. 
Is there a sensible way to generate such command dynamically from current working directory that doesn't involve switching my logic to PHP? A windows-only workaround is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working directory is already in the `%CD%` [environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) (I did not spot it at first because it doesn't show up when you type `set` without parameters). So the command is straightforward:

```
foo.bat init --path "%CD%\\" --quiet
```

Accounting with Composer's peculiar escaping needs we end up with:

```
"i18n-extract": [
    "foo.bat init --path \"%CD%\\\\\" --quiet",
    "foo.bat extras --path \"%CD%\\\\\" --quiet"
]
```